# GCC: -Wall vs -W

Tags: c, gcc, warnings

In **C: A Modern Approach** book, it is said that **-W** provides additional warnings beyond **-Wall**.
And in an example, they have used **-Wall -W** together.

My question is: doesn't **-W** except covering warnings beyond **-Wall**, also provide all warnings of **-Wall**? And if yes, so why they have been used together. Just using **-W** would suffice.

*NOTE: I tried using -Wall over uninitialized variable X. It gave an error, but -W didn't. So I want to confirm: is it for all cases, or does `-W` cover all `-Wall` warnings? Being not so experienced in C, I don't know many errors to test these flags.

Also if anyone knows, please provide me source where I can read and understand GCC in depth.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning%20Options

Answer (score 3):

> doesn't `-W` except covering warnings beyond `-Wall`, also provides all warnings of `-Wall`?

Starting in version 3.4 of GCC (published 2004) the `-W` option was renamed `-Wextra`, though `-W` is still documented as an alias.

In all versions of GCC for which I can find documentation, `-W` / `-Wextra` enables certain specific warnings that `-Wall` does not.  In some versions, there are one or more options that are enabled by the two together but not by either one individually.  But `-W` / `-Wextra` *does not* enable the warnings that `-Wall` does (above and beyond the defaults).  That is, `-Wextra` is not a superset of `-Wall`.

You can find the manuals of many versions of GCC at its [documentation site](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/).  The latest release version is [GCC 13.2](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-13.2.0/gcc/).

Comment: And the warning options for GCC 13.2.0 are found at https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-13.2.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html.

Comment: I just learned recently that -Wpedantic will warn you when you use some (but not all) gcc language extensions, but is also neither a subset or superset of -Wall or -Wextra